# Getting null SecurityContextHolder.getContext() while deleting the User in SpringSecurity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

While deleting the user I am getting below context null.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Below is my controller code:

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{login:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable String login) {
    log.debug("REST request to delete User: {}", login);
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    userService.deleteUser(login);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert("userManagement.deactivated", login)).build();
}
```

Below is regex:

```
public static final String LOGIN_REGEX = "^[_'.@A-Za-z0-9-]*$";
```

Abel to access controller method but when trying to access SecurityContextHolder.getContext() which is coming null.

Below is the scenario:

If we create two users let say login= test6 and login = test@test5.com and both have the same ROLE.
Now we **can't** **delete** test@test5.com and **can delete** test6. So the issue is with login id which contains dot(.) in email or any id which contains dot(.).
So how to upload context with user containing dot(.).

Comment: what is the url you are using when you try to delete `test6` and what is the url you are using when you try to delete `test@test5.com`?

Comment: Can you share your security configuration as well?

Comment: And will you please confirm that it's SecurityContextHolder.getContext() that's returning null and not SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()? It's unclear to me because of the initial code snippet in your post.

Comment: I don't think dot perform any special action in spring security (at least case above) and you will get the null in authentication. Issue might be somewhere else

Comment: Below are the urls: First without dot(.) and second contains dot (.)

http://localhost:8080/api/users/test6

http://localhost:8080/api/users/test.
I am using below code to get the principal out of the Authentication object.
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
And getting SecurityContextHolder.getContext() = null. That is why not able to get the principal.

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` will be null if you are evaluating through debug breakpoint  as it will be on different thread.

Comment: I am not evaluating it in debug breakpoint. I have seen it in log, when I was not able to load User information through principal.